# Outer measure of union of sets defined as subsets of disjoint intervals

Tags: real-analysis

$A_1 \subset I_1$, and $A_2 \subset I_2$, where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are disjoint open intervals.  Prove that $m^*(A_1 \cup A_2) = m^*(A_1) + m^*(A_2)$.

My attempt:

$m^*(A_1 \cup A_2) \leq m^*(A_1) + m^*(A_2)$ is given, because of countable subadditivity

So, to prove: $m^*(A_1 \cup A_2) \geq m^*(A_1) + m^*(A_2)$ 
Consider a sequence of intervals $\{J_{1,k}\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ covering $A_1$, such that all end points of each interval are within $I_1$, and such that $m^*(A_1) \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} J_{1,k}$.  This is possible because of the definition outer measure (infimum of the sum of the lengths of all possible covers).

Similarly, find a sequence of intervals $\{J_{2,k}\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ covering $A_2$ such that all end points of each interval are within $I_2$ and such that $m^*(A_2) \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} J_{2,k}$.

Adding them together, we have  $m^*(A_1) +m^*(A_2) \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} J_{2,k}  + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} J_{1,k}$.

Note that $\{J_{1,k}\}_{k=0}^{\infty}\cup \{J_{2,k}\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ cover $A_1 \cup A_2$.  Therefore, $m^*( A_1 \cup A_2) + \epsilon \geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} J_{2,k}  + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} J_{1,k} $ for all $\epsilon >0$.

Therefore, $m^*(A_1 \cup A_2) \geq m^*(A_1) +m^*(A_2)$

---

I edited the above based on Jake's comments, is it now accurate?

Comment: I think some of your inequalities should be flipped. Since $m*(A_1)$ is the infimum of sum of lengths over all covers, $m^*(A_1)\geq \sum J_{1,k}+\epsilon$. I think this will solve all your problems :)

Comment: Thank you @Jake that is extremely helpful!  Could you tell me if I got it now?

Comment: Pardon me if it is poor form to edit the question after it is asked, but I was not sure how to ask if my new proof is correct or not--it would not fit in a comment.

Comment: It is not always necessary to put in every detail of every inference but it is not a  bad thing to do, and doing so for yourself can help to find potential logical flaws. Here you could say that the inequality in the 2nd-last line follows from the 4th-last line.That is $m^*(A_1\cup A_2)+\epsilon \geq \sum J_{2,k}+\sum J_{1,k}\geq m^*(A_1)+m^*(A_2).$ No flaws.

Comment: It's fine to edit your post after you get some feedback. I'm not happy with your last to second sentence "Therefore $m^*(A_1\cup A_2)+\epsilon \geq \cdots$. In the definition of an infimum over covers, for a chosen epsilon, you are given a cover. Not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks @Jake.  So I could say that for a given $\epsilon >0$, the covers $J_{1,k}$ and $J_{2,k}$ can be chosen so that they are less than $m^*(A_1 \cup A_2) + \epsilon$.  Would that be more appropriate wording?

Comment: Maybe I'm being too picky, but the point is that if you choose an epsilon, you are given just a $\{J_k\}$ that covers $A_1\cup A_2$. You would then BUILD $J_{1,k}$ by $J_k\cap A_1$ and the rest of the argument falls into place.

Comment: @Jake that makes sense, thank you.  However, I think that to build $J_{1,k}$ I can't just do $J_k \cap A_1$, as this would not be a sequence of intervals anymore.  I thought about taking the subcover of $\{J_k\}$ that covers $I_1$, but that is not guaranteed to exist because it is not compact.  Nor can I take the intervals whose end points are in $I_1$ because it is not guaranteed that they exist either.  When constructing $J_{k}$ perhaps I could say to only pick intervals with end points inside $I_1$ or inside $I_2$.

Comment: Ah! I'm sorry. I meant $J_{1,k}=J_k\cap I_1$. Now this will work because $I_1$ and $I_2$ are disjoint intervals